# RXJS: new variable value isn't being sent by observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm very new to RxJs and i'm trying to create a simple Observable that send the new variable value to the component.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong, i guess the Observable does not recognize that the variable is being changed but would love some explanation...

my component:

```
export class NamesListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  public numArr: number[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription 

  ngOnInit(): void {

   this.subscription = this.dataService.getNum.subscribe((value: number) => {
       this.numArr.push(value);
    })
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

my service:

```
export class DataService {


  private privateNum: number = 0;

  getNum = new Observable(subscriber => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.privateNum++
    }, 1000);

    subscriber.next(this.privateNum)
  })

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject.

Also, I think next() should be inside the setInterval():

```
getNum = new Observable(subscriber => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.privateNum++;
      subscriber.next(this.privateNum)
    }, 1000);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I put the .next inside the interval and it worked! why using BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject is better?

Comment: Observable is generic and BehaviorSubject is an observable with specific qualities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the fact that angular's change detection works on references. Since you just push a value in your array, the reference does not change and the change detection does not run.

Try using the following snippet:

```js
export class NamesListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  public numArr: number[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription 

  ngOnInit(): void {

   this.subscription = this.dataService.getNum.subscribe((value: number) => {
       this.numArr = [...this.numArr, value]; // Using the spread operator, this create a new array (a new reference) and triggers change detection
    })
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

I assume you display your array with an `*ngFor` in the template, if that's the case, you could also check [Angular ngForOf doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description), especially the `trackBy` function.